# How to use OR in mod rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^properties-for-rent-in-([^-]*)\.html$ /search.php?var1=$1 [QSA]
```

How would I change this so that it would work for:
 http://www.domain.com/properties-for-rent-in-spain.html
and for http://www.domain.com/properties-for-sale-in-spain.html
(the difference is the rent | sale in the url)

I tried something like

```
RewriteRule ^properties-for-(rent|sale)-in-([^-]*)\.html$ /search.php?var1=$1 [QSA]
```

But this doesn't work.

Any idea's?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example? Because I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you add parenthesis, the $1 group will be rent or sale and $2 - your old match group

Comment: So like this : RewriteRule ^properties-for-^(sale|rent)-in-([^-]*)\.html$ /search.cfm?var1=$2 

Or like : RewriteRule ^properties-for-^($1)-in-([^-]*)\.html$ /search.cfm?var1=$2 [QSA]

Comment: I think, the first.

Comment: That doesn't work. Get 'page not found'

Comment: It gemerate the same link as your first rule in the question. I think  both works or not